# Materialize Chips Initialization using string value from database

Tags: jquery, tags, materialize

I'm trying to initialize chips with a default value from my database. 
Base on the documentation [here](http://materializecss.com/chips.html#properties) 
This is the proper way of doing it.

```
  $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: [{
      tag: 'Apple',
    }, {
      tag: 'Microsoft',
    }, {
      tag: 'Google',
    }],
  });
```

And what I'm trying to do is replace those tag with my own tag by using a single string. 
 Here is what I've tried so far 
I have a string with a value of `{Tag1}{Tag2}{Tag3}`
And I've use this code to replace that string.

```
    var str = Tag;
    var mapObj = {
        '{':"{tag:'",
        '}':"',},"
    };
    str = str.replace(/{|}/gi, function(matched){
        return mapObj[matched];
    });
```

Now when I try to use this formatted string `str` to match the proper initialization format. I don't get my intended result.

```
    $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
        data: [str],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've manage to solve this problem. I'm posting this to help someone with the same problem.

First thing I did was to replace my `mapObj` to

```
    var mapObj = {
        '{':'"',
        '}':'", '
    };
```

So by applying the code above the new replaced value will be from `{Test1}{Test2}{Test3}` to `"Test1", "Test2", "Test3",` notice this is somehow similar to a json format.

Now declare a new variable like this

```
var json = "[" + str + ' " "]';
```

So now its a proper json format. notice that at the end I've added a space `" "` this is to prevent json format error since the replaced value will end in a comma `,`

Next is to parse this `json` and add this `var authData`

```
var jsonChips = JSON.parse(json);
var authData = [];
```

And then this.

```
    for (i = 0; i < jsonChips.length; i++) {
      if(jsonChips[i] != " "){
        var tag = {};
        tag["tag"] = jsonChips[i];
        authData.push(tag);
      }
    };
```

After that I place the authData

```
    $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
        data: authData
    });
```

And its done. Everything is working fine